# How to get the width of all the keyboard characters?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the width of all the characters of the keyboard. I already have the code but it's displaying the whole element width.
I am using different font which is installed locally. However, you can modify the font-family.
The code incorrectly logs the width as 1359. Why?

PS: I am checking in the google chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    @font-face{
        font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
        src: url('Monospace.ttf');
    }
    #checkChar {
        font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
        height: auto;
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<div id="checkChar"></div>
<script>

   var charDiv=document.getElementById("checkChar");

   for(var i = 0 ; i<256; i++) {
    charDiv.innerHtml = String.fromCharCode(i);
        var style = getComputedStyle(charDiv,null);
        var charWidth = parseInt(style.width);
    console.log("i :"+i+"  value :  " + charDiv.innerHtml + " width of char : "+ charWidth);
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see `checkChar` element.

Comment: if the checkChar  element existed, and it is a BLOCK element, then, yes, the width will be wrong - but as the element doesn't even exist, I'm surprised your code gets anywhere past an error **TypeError: charDiv is null** the fact that it's charDiv suggests you are using a DIV ... a block element, don't use a block element

Comment: I have edited the code.
Thanks.

Comment: @Berkay I have edited the code. Thanks

Comment: I am using different font which is installed locally. However, you can modify the font-family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your code

- <s>Firstly, there is no element with id="charDiv"</s>
- Secondly, the fact that the id is `charDiv` suggests it's a `DIV` (if it were present) - which is a block element - i.e. it will usually be as wide as it can be - use a SPAN instead (the ID can be charDiv though)
- thirdly, it is `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`
- Fourthly - `getComputedStyle` won't get the required information for you - use `getBoundingClientRect` instead

Further to `getComputedStyle`. This will retrieve, unsurprisingly, the computed style of an element. The problem is, without any specific `width` (or `min-width` or `max-width`) style, the `width` of an element is, by default `auto`. Therefore, it's a bit *Heisenberg* - sort of - you can't get a quantifiable computed width without assigning a value to the elements width property, but given a width property, you then retrieve the width you assigned, rather than the width of the character.

The code below doesn't include your font, but the solution is sound (add your font as required

```js
var charDiv = document.getElementById("checkChar");

for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
   charDiv.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(i);
   var charWidth = charDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
   console.log("i :" + i + "  value :  " + charDiv.innerHTML + " width of char : " + charWidth);
}
```

```css
#checkChar {
    height: auto;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<span id="checkChar"></span>
```

That should output what you need

Comment: the character width which you are getting is in pixels ?

Comment: yes, [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) returns values in pixels (fractions thereof)

Comment: what is the problem with getComputedStyle(charDiv, null);

How can I get the output using getComputedStyle() ?

Comment: getComputedStyle get's the computed style ... without specifying a width on an element, it's width is computed as `auto` (the default value of width) - adding a width value using CSS would mean you'll get the value added, not the width of the character :p

Comment: Just to nitpick, but this solution is dependent on other styles that could be applied on the testing element. A better way to get the job done would probably be by using [CanvasRenderingContext2d#measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText), or if we really want to use an appended element, then use the [Range#getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) (https://jsfiddle.net/n7cdhkjd/)